# Flutter app run on emulator but not on my physical device

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-test

My Project runs on emulator without any error but when i run it on my physical device it stuck while installing the apk. It does not show any error just stuck on installation.

Comment: Do you have enough space on your physical phone? If so remove the previous version then reinstall. Note that debug version are more large sized than release as contains debug symbols and infos.

Comment: When the app tries to run, are there any errors in debug section? Can you share more details about the error?

Comment: when i run the app, its just stuck on building or installing the app and not show any error.
Launching lib\main.dart on vivo 1907 19 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Parameter format not correct -
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.

Comment: When i run the app on my physical device , its just show the white screen on my device and then stuck

Comment: Yes i have about 60gb of free space in my phone and also i uninstall the previous version of the app and then rerun the project but its still not showing any result and just the white screen occurs.

Comment: I delete the .gradle folder and then run the project, the flutter doctor also have no issue. I also update the Android SDK build-tools,  Android SDK command-line Tools, Android SDK Platform-Tools and also install google usb driver..

Comment: i also run the command "flutter clean" but still not showing any result.